# Consecutive Days count has been reset

Tags: support, consecutive-days

Although I have been visiting the Stack Overflow site for the past 20 days, until 18 day ago the Consecutive Days were shown properly but suddenly the next day it became 1 Day Consecutive.

Is there a bug with Consecutive Days counting? What can we do about it?

Comment: A day is in UTC. It's highly likely that you missed one and that this is not a bug (see the related questions sidebar). You can do nothing about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. SE uses UTC Timezone.
2. Is there a bug with Consecutive Days counting?

   No, I am visiting since last 563 consecutive days and it is working fine. May be yesterday you visited only login page which is not considering as visit. Or if you visit before the 5:30 AM morning ( as you are from India ) then it is considering as same day. Because as per Indian timezone our day counter changes after 5:30 a.m.
3. What can we do about it?

   We ( SE Developer's team ) do not need to do anything, just be careful from next time you visit the site in proper manner.